# How do i can add master code to development branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

I got some git-flow issue. I have a master and a dev branch. My dev branch has updated code and I made a feature branch from it. Now I got a situation that I need same master code in my existing dev branch.

I have few solutions but I don't know which is best practice:

1. Make another dev branch and delete the existing one.
2. Delete existing code from dev and make it the same as master.

Comment: You can also merge in the remote master in your development branch or rebase you dev branch against the master branch. "Best practices" depends if you want to keep the history as is (then merge) or if you want to avoid merge-commits and a tango-history (then rebase).

Comment: k0pernikus no i have a different situation, `dev` is ahead from  `master`, but now i don't need existing dev branch that's why I just want to move dev code to another branch and replace dev same as the master.

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of the followings:

- Make a Pull Request from the `master` branch to the `dev` branch, this way you could pick what changes from `master` you want in the `dev` branch (Probably would result in a merge conflict).
- Open a new `dev` (You should delete the old `dev` first) branch from `master`, this way both of them will be sync.

If you don't care about the content of `dev` and you need EXACTLY the same code that is already on `master` I'll recommend the second, it's faster, but it's a better practice to do this kind of things with a Pull Request.

Comment: `Alberto` 1st one won't work because  `dev` already has `master` code so Pr changes will not appear.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're working alone on the repo**, consider simply moving the ref of `dev` with

```
git branch -f dev master
```

That being said, your `feature` branch, having been branched off `dev`, might still reference commits from the old `dev` you wanted to forget, and they'll be brought back in when you merge into `master`. Be sure to anticipate it if that's the case.

Comment if my assumption is false (if you're sharing the repo), I'll update my answer.